# Error trying to replace a line in bash using awk and sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm studying Bash Scripting in college and I'm having problems creating a functionality that replaces a line.
All I want to do here is allow the user to choose a book on a menu with the choices stored in a database, after that the user should be able to choose the new stock value and then the program should find the line and replace it with another line with the new stock value.
The stock is stored in the fifth column of the file. The data in the database is organized this way:

```
1:O_Mágico_de_Auschwitz:19,80€:José Rodrigues dos Santos:69:2020
```

```
addStock(){
awk -F: '{print $2 " " $5}' baseDados.txt > output.txt
ar=($(cat output.txt))
escolhaLivro=$(dialog --stdout --title "Add Stock" --menu "Livros" 0 0 0 "${ar[@]}" )
echo ${escolhaLivro}
uservalue=$(dialog --stdout --title "Add Stock" --inputbox "Escreve o stock desejado: " 0 0)
nrLinha=$(grep -n "$escolhaLivro" $file | cut -d: -f1)


#this two lines are the ones causing the problems...I cant understand bash quotation
newValue=$(grep "$escolhaLivro" $file | awk -F:  'BEGIN {OFS=":"} $5=$uservalue')
sed -i "$nrLinha s/.*/$newValue/" $file
}
```

Comment: please review [How to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then come back and update your question accordingly; in particular, provide the contents of baseDados.txt, the error and/or incorrect output your code is generating, and the (correct) expected output

Comment: AND you'll do well to read and review: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info . Search for "Before asking about Problematic code" and "How to turn a bad script into a good question" .Good luck.

Comment: Is the purpose of this exercise to solve the stated problem, or to use the tools you have included in your example code (`awk, cat, sed, grep ...` ) ? A better solution to the problem could be generated with `awk`, but that won't be clean either, as only the newest awks have an `--inplace-edit` option (not the exact name). Good luck.

Comment: The reference to `$file` is missing... (but hopefully i guessed the correct value for it )

Comment: Look at results when searching for `[awk] in place edit`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line:

```
newValue=$(grep "$escolhaLivro" $file | awk -F:  'BEGIN {OFS=":"} $5=$uservalue')
```

The awk process has no knowledge of the value `$uservalue`, so it evaluates to `$0` which is the complete line.

You could pass the variable to awk like this:

```
newValue=$(grep "$escolhaLivro" $file | awk -F: -v uservalue="$uservalue" 'BEGIN {OFS=":"} $5=uservalue')
```

After this `newvalue` should have the correct value with changed 5th column.

Comment: awk -F: -v uservalue="$uservalue" 'BEGIN {OFS=":"} $5=uservalue')
This worked perfectly but i still have problems with the last line of my code, what am i doing wrong there?

Comment: opps, changed it to `-v` 

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed the program!Thank you @Luuk**

```
    addStock(){
    awk -F: '{print $2 " " $5}' baseDados.txt > output.txt
    ar=($(cat output.txt))
    escolhaLivro=$(dialog --stdout --title "Add Stock" --menu "Livros" 0 0 0 "${ar[@]}" )
    echo ${escolhaLivro}
    uservalue=$(dialog --stdout --title "Add Stock" --inputbox "Escreve o stock desejado: " 0 0)
    oldvalue=$(grep "$escolhaLivro" $file)
    newValue=$(grep "$escolhaLivro" $file | awk -F: -v uservalue="$uservalue" 'BEGIN {OFS=":"} $5=uservalue')
    sed -i "s/$oldvalue/$newValue/g" $file
    }
```